# javascript generator value of this

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

What is the value of `this` in javascript generators in javascript?
In the below code, both comparisons return false, and when I do a `.toSource()`, `this` appears to be an empty `Object`. References to the ECMA or MDN docs would be helpful, I wasn't able to find anything in either.

```
function thisGenerator(){
    while(1)
        yield this;
}

var gen=new thisGenerator();
alert(gen.next()==thisGenerator);
alert(gen.next()==gen);
```

Comment: `alert(gen.next() instanceof thisGenerator); // true`

Comment: But why is it not equal to `gen`?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I'd guess that your instance is wrapped with a special object that provides the iterator behaviors.

Comment: Found some info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: I've read that before, couldn't find anything on `this`. The case for iterators is quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

`this` still obeys the normal rules.
Considering, the global scope is `window`:

```
var gen = (function() { yield this; })(); gen.next() === window // true
var gen = (function() { "use strict"; yield this; })(); gen.next() === undefined // true
```

In quirks mode, `this` in unbound functions will be the global scope (which happens to be `window`), while in strict mode it is `undefined`.

PS: When calling a function that is bound, everything is still as usual:

```
var o = { foo: function() { yield this; } }; o.foo().next() === o // true
var o = {}; function foo() { yield this; }; foo.call(o).next() === o // true
```